# subprocess works in Python 2 but not in Python 3

Tags: python, subprocess

This subprocess code works perfectly in Python 2, but not in Python 3. What can I do?

Thanks,

```
import subprocess

gnuchess = subprocess.Popen('gnuchess', stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)

# Python 3 strings are Unicode and must be encoded before writing to a pipe (and decoded after reading)
gnuchess.stdin.write('e4\n'.encode())

while True:   
L = gnuchess.stdout.readline().decode()
L = L[0:-1]
print(L)
if L.startswith('My move is'):
    movimiento = L.split()[-1]
    break

print(movimiento)

gnuchess.stdin.write('exit\n'.encode())

gnuchess.terminate()
```

Comment: When it doesn't work, what happens? Do you get an exception? If so, include the traceback. If you get other behavior, please describe it.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely reason for the difference is the change in the buffering behavior, set `bufsize=1` to enable line-buffering.

To avoid encoding/decoding by hand, you could use `universal_newlines=True` to enable a text mode (interpret data using `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` character encoding).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, DEVNULL

with Popen('gnuchess', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=DEVNULL,
           bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as gnuchess:
    print('e4', file=gnuchess.stdin, flush=True)
    for line in gnuchess.stdout:
        print(line, end='')
        if line.startswith('My move is'):            
            break
    print('exit', file=gnuchess.stdin, flush=True)
```

You don't need to call `gnuchess.terminate()` if `gnuchess` accepts the `exit` command.

It seems fragile to read lines until 'My move is' phrase. Investigate whether `gnuchess` provides a batch mode with a more strict output separation.